# Split array values into multiple series values in highcharts

Tags: arrays, highcharts, series

I have this kind of array return:

```
1:{
    0: "COURT_LIGHTS"
    1: "2014-10-01"
    2: "101063"
    3: "576.94"
    4: "576.71"
    5: "0.23000000000002"
  }
2:{
    0: "COURT_LIGHTS"
    1: "2014-10-02"
    2: "101063"
    3: "577.07"
    4: "576.95"
    5: "0.12"
  }
3:{ 
    0: "COURT_LIGHTS"
    1: "2014-10-03"
    2: "101063"
    3: "577.2"
    4: "577.07"
    5: "0.13"
 }
4:{
    0: "PROD_ACU"
    1: "2014-10-01"
    2: "716414"
    3: "6541.67"
    4: "6531.93"
    5: "9.7399999999998"
 }
```

What I want is to dynamically make this values into a series according to its name.

Example:

```
series = [{ date : reading }];
COURT_LIGHTS = [{ array[1] : array[5] }];
```

then plot it in highcharts.

Comment: Do you need help with transforming the array, or configuring the highcharts options, or both? And can you show us what you've attempted thus far?

Comment: i just found out how to work with this kind of array.. my problem now is how to plot every equipments reading... just trying to figure out how to plot these data with in every loop

Comment: If you post whatever code you have so far, and indicate where you're having difficulty, someone will probably help you out. But as it stands right now, this looks like one of those "do my work for me" posts. Those aren't typically well-received by the community, and for good reason.

Comment: ah, sorry for that.. i figured it out earlier, thank you for commenting..